# Activator.CreateInstance throws Exception when references Type moved to another assembly

Tags: c#, .net-4.8, late-binding

I am in the process of refactoring a Legacy Application and want to keep the Plugin System compatible, while getting some issues out of the way.

The problem is, that I needed to move the Interface used for extensions to a different assembly. While doing that, I kept the namespace intact.

In AssemblyB:

```
namespace OldNamespace;
public interface IPlugin
{
  void DoSomething();
}
```

Out at our customers are multiple Plugins, that use this interface, but back when they were developed it was still in AssemblyA like this in CustomAssembly:

```
using OldNamespace;

namespace CustomPlugin;

public class Plugin : IPlugin
{
  // ...
}
```

So the idea is, that this code can stay the same.

My challenge now is, that I want to load the existing Plugins in the Updated application with
`Activator.CreateInstance("CustomAssembly", "Plugin");`
But if I try this, I get the Exception "Could not load type 'IPlugin' from assembly 'AssemblyA'

I don't really understand why it is searched for explicitly in AssemblyA. I never specified in my code, that it needs to load IPlugin from the old Assembly. The namespace is the same and both Assemblies (A and B) are loaded in the application.
Can I somehow control how the Type-Loading for IPlugin is performed? I experimented a bit with the event `AppDomain.TypeResolve` but it wasn't even called.

An option of course is to newly compile the old Plugins, but there aresome, where there is no source code available anymore.

Comment: This looks like a job for `[assembly: TypeForwardedToAttribute( "..." )]`

Comment: _"Could not load type 'IPlugin' from assembly 'AssemblyA'"_ - if that's an actual error message, then that's because `IPlugin` is an `interface` type, and you can't create instances of `interfaces` - so is it possible that you don't actually have a problem at all?

Comment: You need to rebuild those assemblies, because *they* can't find the interface as they're looking in the wrong assembly (namespace notwithstanding). Or use `TypeForwardedTo` as mentioned, but then you still need that assembly to hang around.

Comment: TypeForwardedToAttribute looks promising. Thank you. Keeping the assembly is not a problem. So I would add this to AssemblyA and forward it to B, then it should work hoepfully.
Just for clarification: Do dlls contain metadata, from what other assembly they use a type? I always had the impression, that it just looks up namespaces that are loaded and gets it from there. At least the compiler seems to work in that way and complains when there are two types with the same name in the same namespace in a solution (but maybe this is just to avoid further confusion).

Comment: Yes, assemblies contain a bunch of metadata, including lists of dependencies. You can use something like ILSpy to inspect code and metadata in an assembly.